# How to cache json from URL in PWA?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have created my first PWA page, but have problem with data from URL. On my page Im loading json from URL and this working very well as "online", but I don't know how i can cache this data and load it when my page will works as "offline". Where I have to add this data from URL?
Here is my javascript that load data:

```
fetch('https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfTRolENrC?indent=2')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => obj = data)
.then(() =>{
  var x = document.getElementById("ad");
console.log(obj);
x.innerHTML = obj[0].name;     
      });
```

There is my sw.js:

```
self.addEventListener("install", e =>{
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open("static").then(cache => {
            return cache.addAll(["./","./src/master.css","./images/icon.png"]);
        })
    );
});
self.addEventListener("fetch", e =>{
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request).then(response => {
            return response || fetch(e.request);
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Im not sure that saving fonts are same with JSON from URL. I have to add URL to JSON into line "cache.addALL("URL") and it will be enouth?

Comment: Browsers doesn't care if your external asset is a font, json file or an mp4 movie about pink elephants.

Comment: You are right! :) Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem. You just have to add JSON URL to your static links (where u are giving links to css, img, etc.). It should look like that:

```
self.addEventListener("install", e =>{
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open("static").then(cache => {
            return cache.addAll(["./","./src/master.css","./images/icon.png",
    "https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfTRolENrC?indent=2"]);
        })
    );
});
self.addEventListener("fetch", e =>{
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request).then(response => {
            return response || fetch(e.request);
        })
    );
});
```